Long proof game with rooks
I am trying to track a very special proof game I saw many years ago when I learned about proof games (a board position is given, and the challenge is to find the unique sequence of moves from the initial set-up that reaches the given position in the stipulated number of moves).
The only info I remember is that the final position had only rooks (perhaps 10 per player?), and that the number of moves was ridiculous; something like 35.
That same afternoon I downloaded the program Natch to verify the problem, so I might have found it in a page that linked to the Natch page, although I am not sure of that.
Any leads?

Probably Pronkin & Frolkin 1987 or a closely related proof game in 55+ moves where each side has a King, comically many Rooks, and a few other men.  See for example the accepted answer to Chess Stack Exchange #29362 https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29362.

If the final position had 10 rooks / player then there must be at least 40 moves just to promote them all. I think it's unlikely that the PG is unique, but older problems do allow play to be non-unique
